# Child list elements causing gap between parent ul

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple nav with sub menu's.

I want the `submenu ul` to have a width of `139px` (so on hover, the dropdown box will be 139px in width). However, when I set this, it also creates a gap between the parent links.

**For example**:

In this example, the width between the two links are fine, but when you hover over the `products` link, you can see the gap between `products` and `blog`.

Even if the submenu goes into the area of the blog `li`, that's fine. Just trying to remove the gap for now.

```css
.main_menu>div ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main_menu>div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1.2em 0.9em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* showing dropdown on parent hover */

.item-has-children .menu-children-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: none;
}

.item-has-children:hover ul {
  display: block;
  width: 139px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <div class="menu_container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-has-children"><a href="#">Products ▾</a>
        <ul class="menu-children-wrapper">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add position absolute on opening ul. hope it helps

```css
.main_menu>div ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main_menu>div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1.2em 0.9em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* showing dropdown on parent hover */

.item-has-children .menu-children-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: none;
}

.item-has-children:hover ul {
  display: block;
  width: 139px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <div class="menu_container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-has-children"><a href="#">Products ▾</a>
        <ul class="menu-children-wrapper">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```